# Layering objects in a fluid layout

Tags: css, html, position, absolute

I have an image of a web-browser that I am trying to position a text url over using position:absolute. The problem is that when I adjust the width of the page the text doesn't move the image in the fluid layout.

Device screen with text url example (what i'm trying to achieve): http://matthewhartman.github.io/base/

My code: http://jsfiddle.net/VwkwT/1/

```
HTML:
<div id="primaryContainer" class="primaryContainer clearfix">
      <header id="Header">
        <img id="Logo" src="img/logo.png" class="image" />
        </header>
        <section id="HeroDiv" class="centre">
            <img id="Hero" src="img/browser.png" class="image" />
            <div id="url">www.website.com</div>
        </section>
        <div id="box1" class="clearfix">
        </div>
        <div id="box2" class="clearfix">
        </div>
        <div id="box3" class="clearfix">
        </div>
        <div id="box4" class="clearfix">
        </div>
    </div>

CSS:
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0;
}

.primaryContainer {
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
}

#box1 {
    float: left;
    height: 1190.75px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 153px;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);
}

#box2 {
    float: left;
    height: 759.40625px;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-top: -90.5px;
    clear: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
}

#Logo {
    float: left;
    width: 190px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 13.893926%;
    margin-top: 41.75px;
    margin-bottom: 45.75px;
    clear: none;
}

#box3 {
    float: left;
    height: 733.828125px;
    margin-left: -100%;
    margin-top: 668.90625px;
    clear: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    background-color: rgb(184, 218, 242);
}

#box4 {
    float: left;
    height: 733.828125px;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);
}

#HeroDiv {
    position:relative;
    height: 392px;
}

#url {
    position:absolute;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#8B8B8B;
    font-family: 'Candara', Calibri, Segoe, Segoe UI, Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#Hero {
    position:relative;
    width: 809px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    clear: both;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "I am trying to achieve this" - that is a whole web page with lots of stuff on it. Please be specific.

Comment: height: 733.828125px; <-- you realize there is no such thing a 1/10000th of a pixel.

Comment: img and absolute text should be in the same container. this container can be in relative position if you need to lay your text on a specifiv area. z-index to text to put on top.

Comment: @GCyrillus can you give me an example?

Comment: @user3232801 , here is one used for another question  : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Cxkqf but maybe the fork is easier to analyse http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tiKDB

Comment: @GCyrillus thanks! That helped me solve my problem!